# database design flaw?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm designing a database where a user can make a list. The tricky part (for me) is that every user can make a list with the same title, and have similar items on it. My solution was this to create 3 tables:

```
User-
ID/
name/
email

Title-
ID/
name/ 
date/
userID [FK]

List-
ID/
userID [FK]/
titleID [FK]/
text
```

and the best way I could think of to get the list info was to query the`user ID` with the `title ID` to get their specific list(text) for that title. Right now it won't let me add `titleID` as a FK because it could not add or update a child row, so that begs the question, is there a better way to set it up to make the query easier to get the list?

Comment: When you say they CAN have the same title, what is the probability? If it is a highly common occurrence then a separate table for titles would definitely help with redundancy.

Comment: Do you really need the `Title` table? Why not have just the `User` and the `List` with `listID, userID [FK], title, ...` ?

Comment: Yes the it will be a very high occurrence that is why I have the title table. And also users will have multiple lists

Comment: `List` records only exist in the context of a given `Title` record, so they don't need a `userId` key. Otherwise, this looks like a straightforward parent/child/grandchild hierarchy: a user has N lists that contain M items... So what's the problem, exactly?

Comment: Well when they enter items into their list, and others do as well, it will create multiple entries of the same item, so i was just wondering if there was a better way to create it. Also the list records exist in the context of a given title record FOR EACH USER, so thats why I am a confused

Comment: @Jared: It's not clear. Can a user have (2 or more) lists with **same** title?

Comment: Yes there can be two or more lists with the same title, sorry. Say the title is bread: 1. rye 2. white 3. wheat. Any user can make the list bread, and use the same items although they might list them in different order(but title will be the same).

Comment: edit: Im sorry I read that wrong. Users will only have one title per list.

Comment: @djacobson- Standard parent/child/grandchild hierarchy does apply, thank you. Obv not hard to tell I am new to this. My real question is how to create a query to pull those lists (in the grandchild table). Right now I'm thinking one way to do it is have a SELECT text(my list column) FROM listitems...and then the confusing part, teh only way I can think to do it is ORDER BY listitemsID WHERE titleID=(I have no idea how to do this part, maybe create a variable to get the number I want?

Answer (score 2):

"Title" is a very vague entity-name. I'd recommend User,List,ListItems. Also, consider changing your PK-fields, to UserID, ListID. It will make your sql-statements more readable.

You're saying "Right now it won't let me add titleID as a FK because it could not add or update a child row", is that the db screaming or an application? MS-access or similar?